# deploy rails and angular 5 in same development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, puma

I am using nginix server.I need to deploy both angular and rails in aws ec2 instance. For that, I have copied the content of dist folder of angular app to the root directory of my server.And I run the rails using the command

```
RAILS_ENV=production puma &
```

After that I have provided the IP address in my browser, but I am getting only angular page without data. The api requests is getting response as getting 404 error from nginix.
Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Need more information. Is Rails handling your routing or Angular? Angular has its own routing because it is a Single Page Application, and because of this it does not typically work very well with traditional MVC architecture like Rails.

Comment: Angular has its own routing and it gets data from rails app